# Refresh drawing on Android canvas is too slow

Tags: android, performance, android-sensors

I'm new in android developing. I wrote this code that draws a circle on the screen and by moving the device, the circle will move on the screen. but it is very slow on my Nexus 7 device. Would you help me to  enhance the performance?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

public static SensorManager mSensorManager;
public static Sensor accelerometer;
public static Sensor magnetometer;
public static float[] mAccelerometer = null;
public static float[] mGeomagnetic = null;
private SampleCircle sampleCircle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainForm);
    sampleCircle = new SampleCircle(this);

    layout.addView(sampleCircle);


    layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            sampleCircle.setPoint(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
            return false;
        }
    });

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, accelerometer);
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, magnetometer);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        mAccelerometer = event.values;
    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        mGeomagnetic = event.values;
    }

    if (mAccelerometer != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mAccelerometer, mGeomagnetic);

        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            // at this point, orientation contains the azimuth(direction), pitch and roll values.
            double azimuth = 180 * orientation[0] / Math.PI;
            double pitch = 180 * orientation[1] / Math.PI;
            double roll = 180 * orientation[2] / Math.PI;

            sampleCircle.move((float) Math.floor(pitch), (float) Math.floor(roll));

        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    System.out.println("Acc");
}

private class SampleCircle extends View {
    private Paint p = new Paint();
    {
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }
    private float y;
    private float x;

    public SampleCircle(Context context, float x, float y) {
        super(context);
        this.y = y;
        this.x = x;
    }

    public SampleCircle(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public void setPoint(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void move(float x, float y) {
        this.x -= x;
        this.y -= y;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 50, p);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont call invalidate(); in your onDraw method, call it only when you want to draw a circle in a new position: in setPoint() and move() methods

Comment: did you try to use a traceview http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `View.invalidate()` tells the operating system to redraw the view by calling `View.onDraw(Canvas)`, so calling `invalidate()` in the `onDraw(...)` means that the device will be permanently busy redrawing the view.  So as suggested by @pskink, `View.invalidate()` should be called from the `SampleCircle.setPoint(...)` and `SampleCircle.move(...)` methods.  However, for maximum efficiency, you need to add a tolerance, so that if the move is small, it won't bother to redraw.

Answer (score 0):

The invalidate() should be called in  onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event); and only when noticeable change occurs. This would certainly improve performance